# How to convert a CSV into fixed width text file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, fixed-width

I'm trying to get python to import a CSV file and then export it as a Fixed Width Text File. I can't add the csv file as an attachment. But that's pretty much what I need Python to do. I looked at previous questions about importing and exporting and I'm getting the same issues that they did. Python is importing the CSV and then outputting what looks like a tab delimited file.

Comment: Welcome to StrackOverflow! You will find help here, provided you follow some rules about how questions should be asked. As a new user, you really should read [ask]. Here you should give an extract of your csv file as text so that we can easily copy/paste it, what you want the output file to be for that input, and the code you have tried. Without that, the question is off topic and could be closed. Beware, for Fixed Width Fields files, it is important to say how the widths are chosen.

Comment: Welcome ! can you please edit your question and add sample input and output. It will help the viewers to provide your answer

Answer (score 0):

Load the CSV values, calculate maximum characters needed for each column, open a new file, and for each row of the original CSV, print out formatted CSV data to the new file. You can pad strings with your favourite characters (such as ' ' or '!' or anything else), integers and fixed point decimals should be padded with your preferred amount of leading zeroes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader shows you how to use the csv library to load the CSV file. From that point on, everything should be clear.

Comment: Thank you! I can import the csv. I can read the csv through the console. However, I can't save the file as a text file of any kind. I get I/O text wrapper errors

Comment: You need to open another file to save. You read the first, write to another, then save the other file.